# Scheduled Task using ExecutorService

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I would like to use `ExecutorService` in JAVA to schedule the insertion into database every 5 min.
this the task that i want to execute it:

```
    MyClass{
     a counter that count a handled data received from a Thread
     I receive usually 300 data line/second
     Apply a treatment on these data and keep the results in the memory

    every five minutes {
               update the database with the counters saved in memory*
      }
}
```

Basically it's calling the task each time he get a data from thread running in the background.
and as i have more then 300 data/sec it's impossible to use it in this way.

So what i am trying to do id to  handle the received tasks and keep a counter in the memory and update the database only each 5 min.

My question, is it possible to use these java function `ScheduledExecutorService` to do this, and how can we do it ( i don't want to block my JAVA application on the task for 5min, i want that that application run normally but without executing the task every time, i appreciate if you can show me an example of usage for these function ?

Comment: Did you try to implement it? If no then I would suggest you to try it for yourself and come up with a concrete question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
service.scheduleAtFixedRate(command, 5, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Where `command` is:

```
Runnable command = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      // update database
   }
}
```